# How to return a list of objects in ASP.NET Web API async controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, async-await

How to return a list of objects in the ASP.NET Web API async controller method or wrap a list inside the Task object?

Class:

```
public class SubscriberHistory
{
  public string Date;
  public string Message;

  public SubscriberHistory(string Date, string Message)
  {
    this.Date = Date;
    this.Message = Message;
  }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet("[action]/{accountNumber}")]
public Task<SubscriberHistory> GetSubscriberHistory(string accountNumber)
{
    SubscriberManager subsManager = new SubscriberManager();
    return subsManager.GetSubscriberHistoryByAccountNumber(accountNumber);
}
```

Controller Manager:

```
public async List<SubscriberHistory> GetSubscriberHistory()
{
    List<SubscriberHistory> List = new List<SubscriberHistory>();
    // HttpClient get data
    return List; // ?
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Never return a `Task` from an action method if you are not executing anything `async`: it is useless and will also adds unnecessary overhead to your call.

To return a list of objects, simply declare the correct return type:

```
[HttpGet("[action]/{accountNumber}")]
public List<SubscriberHistory> GetSubscriberHistory(string accountNumber)
{
    SubscriberManager subsManager = new SubscriberManager();
    return subsManager.GetSubscriberHistoryByAccountNumber(accountNumber);
}
```

If you, instead, want to do it asynchronously, then you'll have to return a `Task<T>` and await the result:

```
[HttpGet("[action]/{accountNumber}")]
public async Task<List<SubscriberHistory>> GetSubscriberHistory(string accountNumber)
{
    SubscriberManager subsManager = new SubscriberManager();
    return await subsManager.GetSubscriberHistoryByAccountNumber(accountNumber);
}
```

And in your manager:

```
public async Task<List<SubscriberHistory>> GetSubscriberHistory()
{
    List<SubscriberHistory> list = new List<SubscriberHistory>();
    var result = await client.GetAsync("http://myhost/mypath");
    //Your code here
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Federico! Inside of my method I'm trying to get data from a web service and to do that I have to use the HttpClient class, which in turn uses asynchronous methods

Comment: I added the asynchronous approach inside the answer. Always remember that to be able to use `async`/`await` your entire call chain must become `async` and return a `Task`/`Task<T>`.

Comment: Great! Thank you Federico. That's what i need.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Async Controller, you need to update your code like this:

```
[HttpGet("[action]/{accountNumber}")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetSubscriberHistory(string accountNumber)
{
    SubscriberManager subsManager = new SubscriberManager();
    return await subsManager.GetSubscriberHistoryByAccountNumber(accountNumber);
}
```

There should be async and await in your Controller function if you want to use Async controller.
Thanks!